# If Conditional Loop Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get my macro to find a specific value (a datediff value) and based on that value create a workbook that shows all the rows that have the same policy number (the unique criteria) and the datediff value I specified. The trouble is, my macro doesn't do it for just one policy number, it does it for all with the datediff value I specified. I tried the code below but i keep getting error messages. So Any help would be absolutely amazing!

```
Sub Invoice()

Dim s As Integer
s = 2

Dim t As Integer
t = 21

Dim r As Integer
r = 2

Dim policy As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
policy = Workbooks("Woorkbook2.xlsm").Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & r).Value


If Cells(s, 1).Value = policy Then

Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
mini = Cells(s, 21).Value
If mini = "2" Then

Dim Newbook As Workbook
Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add
Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm").Sheets("Invoice Template (2)").Copy    Before:=Newbook.Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Current Invoice"

Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(s, 1))


Newbook.Sheets("Current Invoice").Cells(t, 2).Value = Cells(s, 10).Value
Newbook.Sheets("Current Invoice").Cells(t, 3).Value = Cells(s, 8).Value
Newbook.Sheets("Current Invoice").Cells(t, 7).Value = Cells(s, 11).Value

Loop

s = s + 1

r = r + 1
End If 
End IF
End Sub
```

Comment: `I tried the code below but i keep getting error messages` - can you clarify please, what error messages exactly have you got and where?

Comment: My major one is from the policy =Workbooks ... Basically what I want it to do is find the value 2 in one column and then group all the rows with value 2 and the same Identifier in the another column together. But I don't know the right code to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the loop should go after the increment of 's':

```
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(s, 1))


Newbook.Sheets("Current Invoice").Cells(t, 2).Value = Cells(s, 10).Value
Newbook.Sheets("Current Invoice").Cells(t, 3).Value = Cells(s, 8).Value
Newbook.Sheets("Current Invoice").Cells(t, 7).Value = Cells(s, 11).Value

s = s + 1

Loop
```

Comment: And perhaps the Loop should also go after the r=r+1 assignment. But I cannot be certain without looking at the Excel docs you're working with.

Comment: The code won't run because it's saying that definition of policy (policy = Workbooks("Woorkbook2.xlsm").Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & r).Value) is invalid/out of range.

Comment: Is there a  different way to say "Do if the cell values are the same"?

Comment: This means that 'r' is probably just looping until it hits the max row value, i.e. .Range("A" & r) is out of range. Also, "Do if the cell values are the same" sounds like just an if statement comparing two cell values, so yes.